# Парсер XML с помощью Boost.PropertyTree

Tags: c++, xml, boost

Не могу разобраться с проходом по xml, структура следующая:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <a>
    <b>
    <p n="s" v="n"/>
    <p n="s" v="n"/>
    <p n="s" v="n"/>
    <p n="s" v="n"/>
    </b>
    <b>
    <p n="s" v="n"/>
    <p n="s" v="n"/>
    <p n="s" v="n"/>
    </b>
    </a>
```

Разбор делаю так

```
void parser()
{

  ptree tree;
  read_xml(XML_PATH1, tree);//читаем наш конфиг
 const ptree & formats = tree.get_child("a.b");

 BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & f, formats){

 // const ptree & proto = tree.get_child("b");

    //BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & p, proto){

      const ptree & atrib = f.second.get_child("<xmlattr>",  boost::property_tree::ptree());
//}
      BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & f, formats){

   std::string tagname = f.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.n").data();
   std::string valuename=f.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.v").data(); //получаем значение value
   opts.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(tagname,valuename));//кладем в массив
   cout<<tagname<<" "<<endl;
   cout<<valuename<< " "<<endl;
       }
      data.push_back(opts);
      pack.request.push_back(opts);
      opts.clear();
       }
    pack.answer.push_back(opts);
    stgdata.push_back(pack);
    pack.request.clear();
    pack.answer.clear();
}
```

Суть вопроса нужно после кажого прохождения по тегу b содержимое заталкивать в pack.

Проблема в том что он каждый раз проходит только по превому тегу b в слеудющий не заходит

полный вариант кода

```
#define XML_PATH1 "./test.xml"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#define ATTR_SET ".<xmlattr>"
using namespace std;//используем стандртное пространство имен
using namespace boost;//используем пространство имен boost'а
using namespace boost::property_tree;//Используем деревья))



void parser()
{
 std::map<std::string, std::string> opts;
  ptree tree;
  read_xml(XML_PATH1, tree);//читаем наш конфиг
 const ptree & formats = tree.get_child("a.b");

 BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & f, formats){

 // const ptree & proto = tree.get_child("proto");

    //BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & p, proto){

      const ptree & atrib = f.second.get_child("<xmlattr>",  boost::property_tree::ptree());
//}
      BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & f, formats){

   std::string tagname = f.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.name").data();
   std::string valuename=f.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.value").data(); //получаем значение value
   opts.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(tagname,valuename));//кладем в массив
   cout<<tagname<<" "<<endl;
   cout<<valuename<< " "<<endl;
       }

       }

}

int main()
{

  void parser();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен, спасибо Марку за подсказку!

```
#define XML_PATH1 "./test.xml"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#define ATTR_SET ".<xmlattr>"
using namespace std; //используем стандртное пространство имен
using namespace boost; //используем пространство имен boost'а
using namespace boost::property_tree; //Используем деревья

void parser()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> opts;
    ptree tree;
    read_xml(XML_PATH1, tree); //читаем наш конфиг
    //ptree & formats = tree.get_child("a.b1");

    BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & fi, tree.get_child("a")) {
        cout << "node b" << endl;
        BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & fj, fi.second.get_child("")) {
            cout << "\tnode n" << endl;// fj.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.n").data() << endl;
            cout << "\t\tn: " << fj.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.n").data() << endl;
            cout << "\t\tv: " << fj.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.v").data() << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    parser();
    return 0;
}
```